# DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message when trying to automatically delete messages

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am trying to create a system that automatically deletes messages in a specific channel if the message does not start with the command prefix AND the user does not have a specific role.

Everything works, but as soon as it deletes one message, it throws the error `DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message`

The following is the code snippet where this error is coming from:

```js
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    function deleteTalk(delay) {
        setInterval(() => {
            if (message.channel.id === "786356926216536102") {
                if (
                    !message.content.startsWith(prefix) &&
                    !message.member.roles.cache.has("791024545091420190")
                ) {
                    if (!message) return;
                    const user = message.author;
                    message.delete();
                    user.send("Please don't talk in report channels.");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }, delay);
    }

    deleteTalk(100);

//Other Code...
});
```

I've looked through questions where people have gotten the same error, but the solutions to those instances haven't worked for me. I've tried to add in code snippets that should prevent the function from firing again if there is no message to delete, but I assume what I had written was incorrect as I am still getting the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put a setInterval so for the first execution your message is deleted but then you try again to delete it 100ms later but the message no longer exists.
For your situation I don't see what the setInterval is for

```js
client.on('messageCreate', (message) => {
    if (
        message.channel.id === '786356926216536102' &&
        !message.content.startsWith(prefix) &&
        !message.member.roles.cache.has('791024545091420190')
    ) {
        const user = message.author;
        message.delete();
        user.send("Please don't talk in report channels.");
        return;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However, you removed the function altogether in your code snippet, which actually made the system not work at all. Even then, your answer still pointed me to the right direction, so thank you!

Comment: You use messageCreate event so it is executed every time a message is sent.

Comment: Well for some reason that isn't the case for me. Not sure why. I'm not gonna bother troubleshooting it though since it isn't causing issues at the moment.

Comment: Glad I could help you out a bit. Don't hesitate if this still bothers you.